# from subquery reuse in where statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

**My problem**:

I want to reuse the table in the from subquery in the where clause. How do I do that?

```
select rID, name, title
from (select statement ...) as t1 
where exists(select * from t1 as t2
            where t1.ratingDate>t2.ratingDate and t1.stars>t2.stars);
```

This gives an error: Error Code: 1146. Table 'sql_stanford_movie.t1' doesn't exist

---

**Goal:**
Return rID such that

- mID and rID aggregated count(stars)=2
- Latest ratingDAte must have higher stars for given mID and rID

**Main table:**

[image]

**Part 1 of solution: After groupby rID and mID and count==2:**

[image]

I make a `temp` table with following:

```
select *
from Rating R1 join 
    (select rID,mID, count(mID)
    from Rating
    group by rID, mID
    having count(mID)=2) as G using(rID,mID);
```

**Part 2 of solution: Check if Latest ratingDAte has higher stars**

[image]

```
select rID, name, title
from temp as t1 
where exists(select * from temp t2
            where t1.ratingDate>t2.ratingDate and t1.stars>t2.stars);
```

---

**But I need to write the whole thing in one statement.**

Comment: You are looking for the `WITH` clause available as of MySQL 8. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: I don't have sql 8. I have only 5.7. :(

Comment: That's too bad. Many things have become possible with MySQL 8. Maybe you *can* achieve what you want in an older version, but that would probably involve a clever use of variables, making the query hard to read. I'd probably just copy that base query and use it twice in the main query for simplicity. Upgrade to MySQL 8 If you can.

Comment: yeah that is one option, but as you say readability goes to hell. thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a CTE:

```
with t1 as (
      . . . 
     )
select rID, name, title
from t1 
where exists (select 1
              from t1 t2
              where t1.ratingDate > t2.ratingDate and 
                    t1.stars > t2.stars
             );
```

A CTE is like a subquery, except you can refer to it multiple times.

That said, I'm guessing that you can use window functions for this.  But the logic you want isn't exactly clear.

Comment: Hi what is unclear in the logic... There are two things I need to adhere to.... 1. `count(stars)==2` for a given `rid` and `mid` combination. 2. need to check the latest date for a given `mid` `rid` combination has higher star rating.

Comment: I would really like to do it with regular functions but don't know how... that is why I first do `groupby` and "pandas transform" the table, to `count(stars)`. Then I use simple where statements to check the 2nd condition.